# Metric perturbation and its properties as scalar, vector and tensor

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, coordinate-systems, perturbation-theory

I am learning the black hole perturbation theory through the original work of [Regge and Wheeler, "Stability of a Schwarzschild Singularity" (1957)](http://reprints.gravitywaves.com/People/Wheeler/Regge-1957-Wheeler_StabilityOfASchwarzschildSingularity.pdf). And in its second page, it claims that the metric perturbation components transform like three types, scalar vector and tensor after we perform coordinates rotation.

> The angular momentum is investigated by studying rotations
> on the 2-dimensional manifold $x^0=T=$ constant, $x^1=r=$ constant.
> Under a rotation of the frame around the origin,
> the ten components of the perturbing tensor transform like
> 3 scalars $(h_{00},h_{01},h_{11})$, 2 vectors
> $(h_{02},h_{03};h_{12},h_{13})$, and a second-order tensor,
> when considered as covariant quantities on the sphere.

So how is this claim correct? Is there any references or is it just a natural conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

Regge and Wheeler discuss the decomposition of metric perturbations in spherical coordinates into parts that transform as scalars, vectors and tensors under $SO(3)$ rotations. Given the coordinates $(t, r, \theta, \phi)$, rotations around the origin with radius fixed only changes the spherical coordinates $\theta$ and $\phi$. Rotation can be seen as a transformation of coordinates $x \to x'$ where $x'^{\mu} = \Lambda^\mu_\nu x^\nu$. Try finding $\Lambda^\mu_\nu$. Now, we want to know how the metric perturbation $h_{\mu \nu}$ transforms under rotations. We know that the metric itself transforms under coordinate transformations as $h_{\mu\nu} \to h'_{\mu\nu}$ where $h'_{\mu\nu} = \Lambda^\alpha_\mu \Lambda^\beta_\nu h_{\alpha\beta}$. From the form of $\Lambda^\mu_\nu$ for you just found, plug it into the transformation rule for metric perturbation under rotations. You will see that some components of $h_{\mu\nu}$ behave like a scalar (that is, the value doesn't change under rotation), some mix and transform like components of a 2-vector, and some mix and transform like components of a 2-tensor.